# How to replace this deprecated method call?

Tags: gwt, deprecated

I'm going through the GWT Tutorials and after entering this line, my IDE complains that
the call to `DateTimeFormat.getMediumDateTimeFormat()` is deprecated:

> lastUpdatedLabel.setText("Last update:
>   " +
>   DateTimeFormat.getMediumDateTimeFormat().format(new
>   Date()));

How do I have to replace the call?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.1.0/gwt-dev-2.1.0-javadoc.jar!/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html#getMediumDateFormat%28%29), you need to use `getFormat(DateTimeFormat.PredefinedFormat.DATE_MEDIUM)`

Answer (score 3):

I could not get the last answer to work.  It gives the same results with just a date stamp.

Try this:

```
lastUpdatedLabel.setText("Last update: " + 
    DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DateTimeFormat.PredefinedFormat.DATE_TIME_MEDIUM)
                .format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Could I have your correction or maybe your opinion, Oliver Weiler ?
Maybe it is too old for you... but I'm new in JAVA and GWT...
I want to know if this following code is a good and efficient solution to this deprecated method.

Google Tutorial give this :
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/codeclient#timestamp

```
  private void updateTable(StockPrice[] prices) {
    for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
      updateTable(prices[i]);
    }

    // Display timestamp showing last refresh.
    lastUpdatedLabel.setText("Last update : " + DateTimeFormat.getMediumDateTimeFormat().format(new Date()));
  }
```

I put this instead

```
  private void updateTable(StockPrice[] prices) {
    for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
      updateTable(prices[i]);
    }

    // Display timestamp showing last refresh.
    DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DateTimeFormat.PredefinedFormat.DATE_TIME_MEDIUM);
    lastUpdatedLabel.setText("Last update : " + format.format(new Date()));

  }
```

Don't know why Google didn't update this tutorial.

Look a confirmation here : https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8241#c3

Thanks to @qbektrix

Answer (score 0):

@Manu, you can replace

```
DateTimeFormat.getMediumDateTimeFormat().format(new Date())
```

with

```
DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DateTimeFormat.PredefinedFormat.DATE_TIME_MEDIUM).format(new Date())
```

It seems like an authentic GWT team answer as i found it at https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8241#c3

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @qbektrix : Look at my answer... the second part, under the "put this instead", said exactly the same as you. Otherwise, thanks for the link at the end of yours.